# Php string manipulation and replacement

Tags: php, string

I am hoping to catch a form value, which always has this format:

```
city-country
```

I can never know what length the city or country has, but I need to be echoed this way:

```
City, Country
```

So in other words, how can replace the - by ", " and Capitalize the first letter of each words?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There *is* a PHP manual with string functions btw: http://php.net/strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### str_replace() + ucwords()

```
$var = 'city-country';

echo ucwords( str_replace('-', ' ', $var) );
```

#### Regular expression

```
<?php

$subject = 'city-country';

$ret = preg_replace('/([^.]*)-(.*)/', '$1, $2', $subject);

echo ucwords($ret);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = str_replace("-",", ",$input);
```

and then use

```
$str = ucwords($str);
```

Answer (score 3):

[String replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is a good tool to start with:

```
$string = str_replace('-', ', ', $old_string);
```

And then [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) will capitalize all the words:

```
$string = ucwords($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = 'city-country';

$new_test = preg_replace('/(\w+)(-)(\w+)/', '$1, $3', $test);

echo ucwords($new_test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$newstr="oslo-norway\n";
$newstr.="stockholm-sweden\n";
$newstr.="copenhagen-danmark\n";

$newstr = preg_replace("/(.)([^-]*)-(.)(.*)/e", "strtoupper('\\1').'\\2, '.strtoupper('\\3').'\\4'", $newstr);

print_r($newstr);
```